# How to handle Refesh-Tokens with GoogleApis for NodeJS Client?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm looking at the following documentation:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens

Especially this part:

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
  if (tokens.refresh_token) {
    // store the refresh_token in my database!
    console.log(tokens.refresh_token);
  }
  console.log(tokens.access_token);
});
```

What I don't understand is why I should store the refresh-token in a database.
Is it due to that the refresh-token is only provided to me on the first authorization?
But even so, shouldn't that mean that this part:

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: `STORED_REFRESH_TOKEN`
});
```

should replace the comment above (// store the refresh_token in my database!)?
A.K.A:

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
  if (tokens.refresh_token) {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token
  });
});
```

This due to Google's statement in the documentation:
"This library will automatically use a refresh token to obtain a new access token if it is about to expire".

What I want to build is an application where people login with their Google-account and then can use several analytics tools I build utilizing f.e Google-analytics API.

I've managed via the documentation to set a valid access-token, but I'm really interested in this topic and really want to learn the refresh-part but have a really hard time wrapping my head around it. If someone could help me understand, I would be really greatful. If not, could someone point me to a great explanation of this (for nodejs) elsewhere? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh tokens exist to keep a balance between security and user experience.
Access tokens should be short-lived ([read more about access token lifetime](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/)), just in case a malicious attacker gets access to it. Without Refresh tokens, you will need to request user authorization each time.

Refresh tokens should be stored in a [safe place](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid.

When you call **oauth2Client.setCredentials** you are initializing the SDK, so it can use the refresh token to fetch a new access token, but the SDK is not storing the refresh token in any long-term storage. That's your application responsibility.

Take into account, a Refresh token can be revoked too, in case it was leaked, or has not been used for six months (for Google APIs). Also, rotating a refresh token regularly is a good security practice.

It's your application responsibility to handle that part too, you can read more about Refresh token expiration [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Comment: Thanks Ruben! So if we translate this to JWTs, a refresh-token should never be stored in a JWT-cookie? What that equals to then is that we should select individual elements from Google's response (necessary for a cooke) but exclude the rest? What I'm thinking of is only including the oauth id for my app (for authentication) since the other authorization-details could be stored in bigQuery. Does that make sense or am I wrong here?

The reason I'm confused is due to the tokens-event. It might make more sense to store the auth-token in a cookie but the refresh-token in the db for ease of use?

Comment: You're welcome, so, this link about token storage can help you to decide what to do since I'm not aware of what type of application are you building https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage